# How to have a force field affecting only one particle system hair

Tags: force-fields

how can i set a force field to affect the particle system named "alpha" and have no  effect to the one named "beta" ?

I tried to bake using separated levels and i tried also using the field weights > effector group setting into the particle system settings pannel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields only have an effect on objects and particles that reside on the same layer. Therefore, one solution is to have particle system 'alpha' on one layer, 'beta' on a second layer, and the force on the same layer as 'alpha'.

To achieve this you can use <kbd>M</kbd> to move objects to different layers - simply press <kbd>M</kbd> while an object is selected and the 'Move to Layer' popup should appear. Just select the layer(s) that the object should reside on (an object can be on more than one layer - hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to allow you to select multiple). To 'View' multiple layers, simply hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the layers in the button bar at the bottom of the 3d Editor window.

With one of the objects (Beta) on a different layer and both layers selected for view, you should see no difference in the scene. However, the moved object's particles will no longer be affected by the force.

Comment: im going to test it right now, tnx for support <3

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I already tried to use different layers but probably something went wrong.

Comment: "layers" became "collections" in blender 2.8. This might be obvious to some but wasn't to me. figured I'd drop it here just in case.

Comment: In Blender 3.6 I add force to its own collection, then add rigidbody to its own collection, but force still acts on the rigidbody, Did Blender 3 remove the ability to isolate physics layers??

Comment: I think Rigidbody still doesn't permit different collections to be affected by their own forces - despite this being possible in Blender 2.79 using  Layers. You could try raising it as a bug report - or search the bug report database to see if it's already been raised and worked on.